# Using Entity Framework or any other ORM in Umbraco

Tags: entity-framework, orm, umbraco

I am trying to find some documentation/article where someone has integrated Entity Framework (or any other ORM tool) in umbraco instead of using good old text based SQL Query.

As of now if I wish to query umbraco database I have write something as follows:

```
ISqlHelper SqlHelper = DataLayerHelper.CreateSqlHelper(umbraco.GlobalSettings.DbDSN)

    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(@"insert into Table(id,ColumnName)                        values(@id,@ColumnName)",
    SqlHelper.CreateParameter("@Id", -1),                    SqlHelper.CreateParameter("@ColumnName", foobar),
```

Which is fine (don't get me wrong) but I think it could be better with some sort of ORM tool.

Any thoughts / ideas about how to use an ORM tool which interfaces existing Umbraco tables as well as new tables?

Answer (score 3):

I have used Linq to SQL in quite a few Umbraco projects but in the last year have moved to using PetaPoco instead. [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) is extremely lightweight, simple to learn, implement and use. It's also very fast.

I found EF and Linq to SQL not particularly Subversion-friendly, causing conflicts when two or more developers were working on the same data schemas.

I also found implementing PetaPoco using DI a lot more straightforward since there were no contexts to consider. To me it feels like a natural fit with the MVC implementation of Umbraco 4.10+ projects.

**Update:**

Having moved on to Umbraco v6+ (which itself uses PetaPoco), I often find I don't even need to install an ORM as I can use Umbraco's own Database object since as I say is actually PetaPoco. However, when I need something with a little more "grunt" I will opt for NHibernate or EF but these situations are few and far between and if possible I will happily still use Petapoco or NPoco.

Comment: Source control part of 'could' only be a problem if you are using edmx. I am talking about POCO objects which works great with any source control system. Ofcourse part of the problem is that its not straight forward in svn to have exclusive checkouts like TFS :)

Answer (score 2):

I use EF extensively within my umbraco apps and it works quite nicely, but not to manipulate the core umbraco tables; I use it to manipulate the custom tables I add to the database.

I am not even sure that the umbraco tables are going to have all the proper foreign keys and/or indexes setup by default to optimize the use of EF and make it worthwhile.

If you just want a wrapper for making the core tables more accessible, consider using a lightweight package such as dapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my two cents. :)

EF or Any ORM mapper you can adopt and pick to work for your needs within umbraco eco system. The benefit will be that you can adopt your own query writing  patter to query Umbraco DB. And It will work perfectly.

You will have queries like following once you adopt EF.

```
var q = from p in cmsContentType.Include("umbracoNode")
```

Likewise.. you can also have some class wrapper to save entities of umbraco table that exists in EDMX.

However if your intention is to have some custom tables as well as Umbraco tables in same database then I recommend you create two EDMX  files- 1 For Umbraco Tables and 2 Nd for Custom tables. This way you can reduce the burden on one EDMX file and gain performance as well.

To answer you question... All though there are no docs available to do this.. you can think like you have whole lots of tables and put them on EDMX and start using it.

Attached below is the image from my database which is vanilla flavor umbraco.

[image]

Comment: I am not big fan of edmx tbh. I prefer POCO which gives me grater flexibility. Either way wouldn't you have the same problem described by @e-j-brennan as below?

Comment: I am marginal fan of e-j-brennan @ SO but I think the DB schema of Umbraco is well define.. if you want to look your self install a fresh one and look at the Database Diagram from SQL server they have good FK-PK relations. as per me. So you will not have problems with EDMS either.